# CURL response return null while use http proxy PHP

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, php-curl

I am trying to call API by using CURL + PROXY, I am using virtualmin admin panel for my VPS. I am getting null header, null boxy, `null error =='roxy CONNECT aborted'` This problem is happen in virtualmin admin panel before this i was use cpanel, in cpanel everything is working fine and i only get response by proxy when i use Shock4 proxy(I remove config in code).

```
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.example.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);

    if($proxy) 
    {
        $splited = explode(':',$proxy); // Separate IP and port
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $splited[0]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $splited[1]); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    }
    if($cookie) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'cookie');

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if(!$httpcode) return false; else{
        $header = substr($response, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
        $body = substr($response, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
        curl_close($ch);
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        return array($header, $body);
    }
```

I think some firewall block this request
I don't have much knowledge in linux, i m using ubuntu 18.*

Comment: The proxy maybe very slow and you could try to increase the timeout.

Comment: Did you forget the `$` sign? `if($cookie) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, cookie);` at the end of the line?

Comment: `if(!$httpcode) return false; else{` is invalid syntax. You should wrap the `return false;` into curly brackets.

Comment: @MarkusZeller proxy is high speed and working, I was checked it on cpanel with same ip, when i switch to virtualmin admin panel http proxy not working anymore. I think some kind of firewall block it. i am using php 7.0, Because http proxy has to work with firewall, Just like i mention shock4 proxy only work because shock4 ignore or no need to allow by firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I like answer my own:
In Virtualmin Admin Panel, goto->webmin->networking->click on add port->set single port or set port in range-> save setting then click on apply configuration then reboot your machine;

Its work for me.